Good dotted line contrast style
I've done a quick search online and couldn't find any results for this in particular. What I have is an image editing user interface that needs to display dotted lines over the image as guide lines. I'm running into the issue of contrast.
Since I can't control what the image data looks like, I need a way for the dotted line to be easily visible on any background. My first thought was to make the dotted line invert the color of the background, but in many cases this just looks noisy and still difficult to see. It also gets more difficult to see on a background whose color is very moderate.
I've tried also adding a half to color values, and wrapping them around when they exceed 1.0. This also raised the same issue of high noise though in some situations.
What I'm wondering is if there is a good standard way to render a dotted line on a background that minimizes these issues of contrast and noise.

You could add an option to change the colour of the dotted line to light, medium or dark, possibly light grey, medium grey or dark grey. That would give people the option to set based on the image and their preference.
